# React component doesn't receive props after Redux store update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

What does work:

- Saga pulls the data from an API. The reducer for `UPDATE_LOTS` fires up and returns the new state.
- Redux store is updated with the correct data as can be observed in the chrome extension and through logging.

What doesn't work:

- The `componentDidUpdate` never fires up. Nor does `componentWillReceiveProps` when replaced by it.
- Since the component never received an update, there's no re-rendering either.

Most of the advice on this topic discusses how people accidentally mutate the state, however in my case I don't do that. I've also tried the following construction `{...state, lots: action.data}` instead of using ImmutableJS's `Map.set` with no luck.

Any ideas? Not listing the saga files here because that part of the data flow works perfectly.

The component:

```
class Lots extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.props.onFetchLots();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('updated', this.props.lots);
  }

  render() {
    const lots = this.props.lots;
    console.log('render', lots);
    return (lots && lots.length) > 0 ? <Tabs data={lots} /> : <div />;
  }
}
```

Mapping and composition:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onFetchLots: () => {
      dispatch(fetchLots());
    },
  };
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    lots: state.lots,
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'lots', reducer: lotsReducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'lots', saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(Lots);
```

Reducer:

```
export const initialState = fromJS({
  lots: false,
});

function lotsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_LOTS:
      console.log('fetch lots');
      return state;

    case UPDATE_LOTS:
      console.log('update lots', action.data.data);
      return state.set('lots', action.data.data);

      default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the kind of question that would be much easier to figure out with a Code Sandbox that replicates your issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything was correct except for the `mapStateToProps` function.

Since ImmutableJS was used, I had to access the state property as `state.get("lots")` instead of `state.lots`.

Doing so fixed the problem.